# Largest possible number of vertices in this graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph, with $|E| = 19$ and $deg(v) \geq
>  4$ for all vertices $v$ in $V$
>
> What is the largest possible value of $|V|$ ?

Well I know that the sum of the degree is equal to two times the number of edges and so $\sum deg(v) = 2 \times 19 = 38$

Now I think if we want to find the largest possible value of $|V|$ then we try to minimize the degree of every vertex but we have that $deg(v) \geq 4$ and so $\frac{38}{4} = 9.5$ but we can't have fractions in our answer, and if we take $9 \times 4 = 36$  that can't happen, then we can have $8$ vertices each with degree $4$ and the last one should be degree $38 -32 = 6$

So My final answer is $9$ vertices, $8$ of them with degree $4$ and one of them has degree $6$ does that make sense ?

Comment: This is almost enough, but you should exhibit such a graph; how do you know that one exists? Some degree sequences are impossible, such as having two vertices, each with degree 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct: your graph is $W_6$ with two additional vertices, which connect each to three different vertices on the cycle of the wheel and also to each other - so $|V| = 9$. The only vertex with 6 vertices is the wheel center vertex.